# Prove that an ideal in $C[x]$ is a max ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers, ideals

I need to prove that the ideal $$I = (f=x+y^3, g=y+x^2+2xy^3+y^6)$$ in $C[x]$ is a max ideal.

I found the variety $Var(f,g)$ in $C[x,y]$ is ${(0,0)}$ but I do not know what to do next. How to show that this ideal is maximal in $C[x]$ what about this ideal when we look at it in $C[x,y]$?

Comment: You mean a maximal ideal of $\mathbb C[x,y]$, I suppose? I dont' understand how you'd be interpreting $y$ in just $\mathbb C[x]$, but you seem to have deliberately used it three times.

Comment: In the problem statement it says $C[x]$ but if it does not make any sense (might be a typo), then how to show that it is maximal in $C[x,y]$?

Comment: $g=y+x^2+2xy^3+y^6=y+(x+y^3)^2$. therefore the ideal is the same as $(x, y)$.

Comment: Thank you! Can we use Hilbert Nullstellensatz to prove it? Since the variety is $(0,0)$ then is corresponds to the ideal generated by (x-0, y-0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $g=y+(x+y^3)^2=y+f^2$. Therefore, $y \in I$ and so $x \in I$. Thus, $(x,y) \subseteq I$ and so $(x,y)=I$ because $(x,y)$ is maximal and $I\ne\mathbb C[x,y]$ because all $h\in I$ satisfy $h(0,0)=0$.

Bottom line: $I=(x,y)$, a maximal ideal.